# Reputation tab shows invalid data if bounty is offered for more than 250 rep

Tags: bug, reputation, bounties

The blue text on the reputation tab (e.g. you have a new notification text) that disappears after being clicked on has a small bug.

If I offer a bounty for more than 250 rep (500 in my case), then the total displayed in the notification is calculated as if I hit the maximum of 250 of downvotes.

1. I visited the tab before offering the bounty (clearing it).
2. I received 12 points in upvotes and such.  The tab showed 12.
3. I offer a 500 point bounty. Blue text shows 238.  The black text on the tab is correct.

I don't have a screenshot.

**Unimportant questions**

- Does this imply that there is a maximum downvote in a day of 250?
- Has this ever happened to anyone?

Comment: Do you have  a screenshot by any chance, for it may help

Comment: If you mean it's showing -500 that's how it should be. It's showing the reputation earned since you last visited your reputation tab. :)